# Accessing Camera in Ionic 3 App running on a browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I have ionic 3 app having following code to access Camera .

```
takePhoto() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    targetWidth: 450,
    targetHeight: 450,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
 };

   this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
    imageData => {
      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
      this.photos.reverse();
      this.sendData(imageData);
     },
     err => {
       console.log(err);
     }
     );
}
```

It works perfectly fine and takes picture if my platform is android/ios.  But when I try to run my app on platform 'browser' and access through mobile I get following error(Both on Safari or Chrome).

[image]

What is the way to access Camera/gallery in mobile if my platform is browser?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `cordova-browser` is a platform for testing purposes only, you shouldn't use it to target real browser apps.

`cordova-plugin-camera` uses `navigator.getUserMedia` for browser platform, so it should work fine on Safari on iOS 11, but not in older versions. It won't work on Chrome because Chrome for iOS is just a regular webview and webviews don't support `navigator.getUserMedia`.

If you want to pick files from the phone, you can use an input tag with type file.

```
<input name="myFile" type="file">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just want to the reason on why cordova-browser should not be used for real browser apps?

Comment: @Arpit it's more my opinion than a real reason. It was created to easily test the apps without deploying/building the app, not to be used as a real platform. Nowadays the platform is a bit more mature, but the plugin support is far from the other platforms (also because most things plugins do are not possible on the browser yet)